# R user/custom defined primitives?

Tags: r, function, primitive

**is it possible to define your own primitives in R? (or things that look, feel and work like primitives)**

I'm talking new versions of `$`, `[`, `for(){}` etc.

For example i might want a primitive `£` that works similar to `$`, but it accesses elements from a list of lists like this

```
list_of_lists<-lapply(1:10,function(x){list(a=1,b=2)})
list_of_lists£a 
# return a list of all elements called  `a` from list_of_lists
```

The closest I got to this is:

```
`%£%`<- function(x,y){
     lapply(x,function(x){x[[y]]})
}

list_of_lists<-lapply(1:10,function(x){list(a=1,b=2)})
list_of_lists%£%"a"
# return a list of all elements called  `a` from list_of_lists
```

Is there a way to define this so that it works exactly like a "real" primitive?
I'm not interested in this specific problem, I want to know how/if in principle I can define my own versions of `$`, `[`, `for(){}` etc

Comment: You are conflating two issues: a primitive is a function with a (particular) efficient implementation (i.e., not a closure). If you want the parser to recognize a new operator `£` you need to modify the parser, which is not possible as a user and R programmer.

Comment: thanks Roland! I get your point; I don't need/want it to be actually implemented "deep" inside R - I'm only trying to mimic the behaviour from how the syntax looks to the R user. But essentially you are saying this is not possible?

Comment: Yes, you can't define arbitrary operator symbols.